# How do I get the reader out of a Lucene Document's field?

Tags: java, lucene, document

I would like to read the contents of this text file as a string, which is in the Lucene Document format. I understand that I can do this by getting the field which contains the reader. How can I do this? Below is the document object.

```
Document<stored,indexed,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<FileName:20150503.pdf> indexed,tokenized<Content:java.io.FileReader@2781e022>>
```

Currently, I am reading off my partners' code and I see that a reader is added into a field of the document. However, .getFields("Content") doesn't return the reader to me, but instead an indexable field.

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(txtFile);
document.add(new TextField("Content", reader));
```

How can I get the reader out of the Document object?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by that. Isn't it a binary file?

Comment: I currently have this Document object and I want to read its contents as a string.

Comment: What field is the text file in? I mean, presumably you put it there. You might want to take a step back for a second and check out how you're actually storing your docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`Field.readerValue()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#readerValue()).

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I am now getting a steam closed IO error. How can I read from this reader without this error?

Comment: No idea without seeing the code concerned. Do you mean it is closed as soon as you first use it?